# What is the difference between concept learning and classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I've recently read about concept learning in a machine learning class. They defined a concept as (translated from German):

> Concept:
>
> - Describes a subset of objects or events defined on a bigger set.
> - Boolean function defined on bigger set
>
> Given: Examples which are labeled as members or not-members
>
> Searched: Automatically infer the definition of the underlying concept
>
> Definition of concept learning: Infering a boolean-valued function from training data of its input and its output.

I would call this a 2-class classification problem. Is there a difference?

Comment: Nice question.  Are there any online links, which can help us learn more about the concept of _concept learning_?

Comment: @Dawny33 Just for reference if others find this question: http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~monsefi/machine-learning/pdf/Machine-Learning-Tom-Mitchell.pdf Chapter 2 is about concept learning and this question stems from their definition

Answer (score 3):

The objective is rather different.
For classification problems, we want to know: GIVEN X, WHAT WILL BE Y?
For concept-learning problems, we are asking: WHAT KIND OF X WILL GIVE US Y?

It may seem similar, but for classification problems, we may use a model that is unable to generalize and answer "WHAT KIND OF X WILL GIVE US Y" until you plug X into the model (e.g. K-nearest neighbor).

On the other hand, concept-learning problems, the main issue is to generalize and answer what can be X specifically.

Comment: Which algorithms would be used for concept learning?

Comment: This slide: http://ml.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/_media/documents/teaching/ss09/ml/version.pdf outlined a few algorithms for concept learning

Comment: So with techniques like the ones used in deep dream / the ones presented by Matt Zeiler in [Visualizing and Understanding Deep Neural Networks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghEmQSxT6tw) one can say that the CNN is learning the concept of "cats" and can of course be used to classify images as "cats"?

Comment: It still seems to me that any learning algorithm for classification can be used to generate instances of the class. Hence all classification algorithms would also be concept learning algorithms?

Comment: No. classification only has a model p(y|x), so can't generate x's given y -- p(x|y). You could do that with a generative model only, which learns p(x,y), like naive bayes for example. Maybe this is what concept learning is in modern terminology?